# OpenJDK crashing and autoclosing programs

Tags: linux, debian, java, eclipse, openjdk

I use Debian Wheezy, and frequently make use of Java applications that are famous for being memory-hungry (namely Eclipse variants NetBeans and Aptana Studio 3 on RadRails or PyDev modes). I was having no problem at all with them when I used Oracle JRE. However, I'm using OpenJDK since my last formatting and I started having random unexpected exits from the apps. I then ran Aptana Studio via the terminal so I could see any error messages, and there is what I got when the program closed:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0xb00b803d, pid=4748, tid=3076118208
#
# JRE version: 7.0_25-b30
# Java VM: OpenJDK Client VM (23.7-b01 mixed mode, sharing linux-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libsoup-2.4.so.1+0x5603d]  soup_session_feature_detach+0x1d
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/gabriel/hs_err_pid4748.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
# instructions on how to reproduce the bug and visit:
#   http://icedtea.classpath.org/bugzilla
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

Is this some known issue with OpenJDK or some problem in my machine? How can I solve it? I really need these programs for work.

Thanks!

Edit 1: As Chris suggested, I checked ~/hs_err_pid4778.log. It contains [this log](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=wZ1EXTui), but all I could see from it was that Aptana caused the problem, which I already expected. However the crash seems to be caused by many different modules/methods? I still have no idea how to solve that.

Answer (score 0):

Look for clues in `/home/gabriel/hs_err_pid4748.log`...

Why do you suspect this is OpenJDK issue and not - foir exmaple - Oracle JDBC's, heap space?

Comment: I actually suspected OpenJDK because it was the only possible culprit in my mind - apart from hardware failure - since I don't understand much about how Java works. I think you assumed I did because I use Eclipse - however I only use it for Python and a few web-driven high level frameworks.

Comment: Check the OP again; I've edited the logs in.

Comment: Update OpenJDK, give  your app more memory.

Comment: Tried those. I gave 1024M Xmx to Aptana Studio and it still crashes. Logs are too similar so I did not include them this time. I guess it's a problem with Aptana Studio on its own, but it would be strange since I don't seem to find people with the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

**Use the Oracle JRE.**

My company's software, which I'm a developer for, lives on Linux & Java. We used the OpenJDK for a while, but we'd get very random crashes, few and far between. One day, I updated all our OpenJDK instances and started having major issues with our GUI. As soon as I switched to the Oracle JRE, everything worked fine again. No more random/obscure issues.

OpenJDK is supposed to be ~99.99% of the same code as the Oracle release. I guess that 0.001% fills in some pretty key gaps.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'll do for now. Not accepting because it doesn't particularly solve my problem and someone can come up with the fix.

Comment: @gchiconi: Yup, I wouldn't accept it either, at least, not for a long while. I hope someone gives you a more direct & specific reply. Seems like OpenJDK is soo close. For me, I've got other fish to fry..